# How to prove that the grammar G is not LL(1)

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

The grammar is:

```
L => LE | E
E => (C) | (F) | V | T
C => ifEE | ifEEE
F => +L | -L | *L | printL
V => a | b | c | d
T => 0 | 1 | 2 | 3
```

I think it is not LL(1) because of C => ifEE | ifEEE, but I am not sure if it is correct... Can anyone help me to prove that it is not LL(1)? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your grammar is ambiguous so it is neither LL(k) nor LR(k). You can show that by finding a sentence with two distinct parses, which should be simple (search for "dangling else" for examples.) But the two productions you mention clearly stop it from being LL(1), because they both need to be in the predict set for `if`.